# Tableview cells lines disappear

Tags: swift, uitableview

Does anyone have an official answer as to why some tableview cell lines disappear on scroll? Is this a glitch? I've seen some answers on how to remove them but what is causing this problem to begin with?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DisplayHeader") as! DisplayTVC

        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PictureDisplay") as! PictureTVC

        cell.collectionView.reloadData()

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `cell.collectionView`, and why are you calling `cell.collectionView.reloadData()` within your `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: That seems like a really bad idea...

Comment: @CharlieFish How is this a bad idea? This is a collectionview inside of a tableview cell. It works purposely fine. I've edited my question however to be more specific. It is actually the tableview separators that disappear on scroll.

Comment: Re cells disappearing, is the cell missing or present and blank or sized such that it merely seems like it “disappeared”. I’d suggest exercising the app to reproduce this undesirable behavior and then using the view debugger to really diagnose what’s going on. But there’s not enough here for us to diagnose the problem for you. We’d need a [simple, complete, and reproducible example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you further.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I've edited my question. It is the tableview cell separators that disappear on scroll. Which is pretty strange to me. I don't have any code that is messing with the separators.

Comment: I've had this before. I'm pretty sure my cell was not sized correctly and the bottom element was messing with the separator. Try increasing the cell height and see what happens.

Comment: When you're scrolling your `tableView`? The `cellForRowAt` will be called automatically. Therefore you shouldn't reload this `tableView` manually. Do not use this line of code in your delegate method: `cell.collectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: Use a `print statement` in your `cellForRowAt` and you can see what actually happens

Comment: @ILoveToCode22 I would just be curious to see the performance implications of calling that there.

Comment: In Simulator most of time tableview cell separators not show but in Real Device tableview cell separators must show.

Comment: @Mannopson Adding Renders with edge antialiasing in the plist file fixed the problem for me. I was just wondering if this is a glitch in Xcode. I'm assuming so